# Why can I instantiate objects of abstract classes and interface? What is the super in constructor?

Tags: java

Here I instantiate objects from two abstract classes and an interface. I wonder why I can do that in three cases, especially the case of NotShape class where there is no abstract method. And the second question is that, What is the "super" when I instantiate the object of NotShape class? Is it belong to Object class or NotShape class itself? I thank you so much.

```
abstract class Shape{
    String descrOfShape = "This is a shape";
    abstract void draw();
}

abstract class NotShape {
    String descrOfNotShape = "This is not a shape";
    void printInfo() {
    System.out.println("Can't be measured");
    }
}

interface Test{
    int ID = 10;
    void showResult();
}

public class InstantiateObjects {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Shape s = new Shape() {
            @Override
            void draw() {
            }
        };

        NotShape ns = new NotShape() {
            @Override
            void printInfo() {
                super.printInfo(); /*What is the super? Is it belong to Object 
                                class or NotShape class?*/
            }
        };

        Test t = new Test() {
            @Override
            public void showResult() {
            }
        };

        System.out.println(s.descrOfShape);
        System.out.println(ns.descrOfNotShape);
        System.out.println(t.ID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not instantiating an abstract class or interface, you're instantiating a private anonymous extension/implementation of the abstract class/interface.

More reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

Here You implementing **interface or abstract class** on your main method. You can not instantiate  abstract class or interface never. But you can inherit then from another class or interface(depends on inheritance rules). Here you are instantiate a **anonymus** class which means you are **implementing your interface or extending your abstruct classes**. And your

```
@Override
void draw() {
}
```

and

```
@Override
void printInfo() {
    super.printInfo(); /*What is the super? Ans: super means its call its parent class. Is it belong to Object class or NotShape class? Ans: Obviously its belongs to  parent class NotShape*/
  }
```

They are obviously **overiding** super classes(interfaces and **abstruct** classes) methods. You can try this then you can see its overiding your printinfo method

```
  NotShape ns = new NotShape() {
            @Override
            void printInfo() {
                super.printInfo(); /*What is the super? Is it belong to Object
                                class or NotShape class?*/
            }
        };

        ns.printInfo();
```

That means you are calling your **anonymus classes** method. and then its calling your **super** classes because you are calling **super.printInfo();**

**NB:** take further study on highlighted terms. Thanks.